# Script "vsdevcmd\ext\Active" could not be found

Tags: visual-studio-2022, build-tools, cl.exe

I am trying to compile a library named "triangle". For that i need C++ build tools. I have installed those but when i open developer command prompt for vs 2022 i got the following error

```
Active code page: 936
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2022 Developer Command Prompt v17.9.4
** Copyright (c) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Script "vsdevcmd\ext\Active" could not be found.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] *** VsDevCmd.bat encountered errors. Environment may be incomplete and/or incorrect. ***
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] In an uninitialized command prompt, please 'set VSCMD_DEBUG=[value]' and then re-run
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] vsdevcmd.bat [args] for additional details.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Where [value] is:
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    1 : basic debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    2 : detailed debug logging
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]    3 : trace level logging. Redirection of output to a file when using this level is recommended.
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat] Example: set VSCMD_DEBUG=3
[ERROR:VsDevCmd.bat]          vsdevcmd.bat > vsdevcmd.trace.txt 2>&1
```

Where as while compiling "triangle" i get the following error:

```
building 'triangle.core' extension
cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVOID=void -DREAL=double -DNO_TIMER=1 -DTRILIBRARY=1 -DANSI_DECLARATORS=1 -Ic -IE:\anaconda\envs\py39env\include -IE:\anaconda\envs\py39env\Include /Tcc/triangle.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\c/triangle.obj
error: command 'cl.exe' failed: None
```

Comment: And did you try what the error message suggests you to try? `set VSCMD_DEBUG=3` then `vsdevcmd.bat > vsdevcmd.trace.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Yes here is the trace file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DmcYmKJFgboOZgZQORnoe1KA_nzvO05l/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 1):

**Fixed!!**
The problem was because of this line `Active code page: 936`
Solution:

1. `Start -> Run -> regedit`
2. Go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun]`
3. Change the value to `@chcp 936>nul`
   Just put `>nul` at the end of your code page value, so that command prompt does not produce any output when run